# PHP: cURL download ZIP file - smaller filesize

Tags: php, curl, download, zip

I'm trying to download a ZIP-File from external server to own server. The PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php    
...
# Some URL
$URL = 'https://xyz.source.com/Path/where/ZIP-Files/file.zip'; 
# Destination
$destination = fopen("../path/to/file.zip","w+");   

# Check, if cURL is installed: 
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
    die('cURL it not installed!'); 
}

# New cURL Session
$ch = curl_init();

# Set Options 
# Set Download-URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
# unknown about Header 
# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

# Set to "false", but I don't know why due to lack of explanation. 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

# Set to "true", but I don't know why, due to lack of explanation.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $ziel);

# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');

# Execution 
curl_exec($ch);

# Check for errors
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
     echo 'Curl-Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo 'cURL - no problems';
} 

# end of cURL-Session
curl_close($ch);


fclose($destination); 
...
?>
```

*What happened? - there is a file, but smaller size:*

On destination-Server, I get a file with smaller size than expected. Smaller ZIP-File can't be opened.

Comment: why should it work? you open `$destination`, but are pointing curl at `$ziel`, which is an undefined variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really making this more complicated than it needs to be:

```
<?php    
...
# Some URL
$URL = 'https://xyz.source.com/Path/where/ZIP-Files/file.zip'; 
# Destination
$destination = "../path/to/file.zip";

$filedata = file_get_contents($URL);
file_put_contents($destination, $filedata);
?>
```

See documentation on how to use [`file_get_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: Thank you very much. Download works! And also thanks for the helpful link to the docmentation.

Comment: After exeriencing a little bit with "file_get_contents($URL)", I identified that this command does _not_ download the complete file, just part of it. The ZIP-File to download is about 1,5 MB, but the command does only download 1121 Byte (!) - sometimes some more, sometimes some less. The downloaded ZIP-File is completele worthless. 

So are there any  alternatives?

Comment: That would be a problem with the server you're downloading from.

Comment: But when I use the same URL to the ZIP-File and put it into a browser address field, I'm able to download the ZIP-File manually. Therefore, the server where I'm downloading from, is OK.

Comment: I've added the Parameter "FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH" and changed to "$filedata = file_get_contents($URL, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);" The download works now.

Comment: [at] miken31 I suppose, you are right. After some tries, I've seen that download works _sometimes_ now. It seems that external server was overcrowded before.